# How to differentiate lines with one dot and two dot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, distinguishedname

I want to extract  a specific part of a sentence. My problem is that I have a list of sentences that each have different formats. For instance:

```
X.y.com
 x.no
 x.com
 y.com
 z.co.uk
 s.com
 b.t.com
```

how can I split these lines based on the number of dots they have? If I want the second part of the sentence with two dots and the first part of the sentences with one dot

Comment: Can you elaborate? So for `b.t.com` you want the `t`, but for `x.no` you wanted the `x`?

Comment: yes exactly that is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anwser your question you could use [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) to count the number of times the '.' appears and then do
whatever you need.

```
>>> 't.com'.count('.')
1
>>> 'x.t.com'.count('.')
2
```

You could use that in a loop:

```
for s in string_list:
    dots = s.count('.')
    if dots == 1:
        # do something here
    elif dots == 2:
        # do something else
    else:
        # another piece of code
```

More pythonic way to solve your problem:

```
def test_function(s):
    """
        >>> test_function('b.t.com')
        't'

        >>> test_function('x.no')
        'x'

        >>> test_function('z')
        'z'
    """
    actions = {0: lambda x: x
               1: lambda x: x.split('.')[0],
               2: lambda x: x.split('.')[1]}
    return actions[s.count('.')](s)
```

Comment: there are thousand of these lines I cannot count them seperatly

Answer (score 2):

You want the part directly preceding the last dot; just split on the dots and take the one-but last part:

```
for line in data:
    if not '.' in line: continue
    elem = line.strip().split('.')[-2]
```

For your input, that gives:

```
>>> for line in data:
...     print line.strip().split('.')[-2]
... 
y
x
x
y
co
s
t
```

Comment: I have tried this and I keep get this error"IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user2058811: Then you have a line without a dotted name; updated to skip those.

Comment: If the lines can contain multiple dots, `rsplit(".", 2)[-2]` should be a little bit faster as it doesn't perform unneccessary splits. Probably doesn't matter for OPs case though...

Comment: @l4mpi: I was presuming that by 'sentence' the OP actually meant 'line' and that all we find on the line is the dotted name. :-)

Comment: yes the lines contain multiple dots and some of them may do not contain any. How should I skip them ?

Comment: @user2058811: I already updated the code to skip lines that do not contain any dots.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this logic:

For each line:

- remove any spaces at beginning and end
- split the line by dots
- take the part before last of the splitted list

This should give you the part of the sentence you're looking for.

Comment: Which is really easy to code in Python; why don't you include an example or demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the split function.

```
a = 'x.com'
b = a.split('.')
```

This will make a list of 2 items in b. If you have two dots, the list will contain 3 items. The function actually splits the string based on the given character.